# Required Field Validator + AsyncFileUpload

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, validation

I have been trying to apply the default ASP.Net Required Field Validator to an AsyncFileUpload control (from the AJAX Control Toolkit).

---

## The Scenario

I have created a Web User Control. **Let’s call it wucFileUpload.**

wucFileUpload has an AJAX Update Panel that is wrapping the Required Field Validator and the AsyncFileUpload. *(I have to use the AJAX Update Panel for some particular reasons)*.

wucFileUpload is going to be used in many pages, and in some of them, this control is going to be generated automatically, so I do not know how many of them I will have per page.

wucFileUpload has a property called Required. If Required is true, it will enable the Required Field Validator, to check if the AsyncFileUpload has been filled at least once.

---

## My try

I found [this solution here on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2983909/how-to-add-required-validator-to-ajax-asyncfileupload), and I tried to apply it. However, my case is a little bit different, from the one represented on that question.

---

## My thoughts

I really liked the idea of having a hidden Textbox or a HiddenField. Because a single AsyncFileUpload can upload N number of files.

The Textbox **could get some value on the first time OnClientUploadComplete runs**… this way I’ll know the user has uploaded at least one image.

But I would also need a way of **clearing that Textbox**, because the user can delete the image that he just uploaded. And if the does that, then the field must be validated again.